# How to point to an JS Array by Name in the Form of String?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a JS array.

```
//This is Dynamic, I maynot know the name in the beginning
var myArray = ["apple","ball","cat"];

var NameOfArray = "myArray";
```

How can I access myArray if I know only it's name in the form on String? 
In PHP, I would use `$$`. How Do I do that in JS?

Comment: I think this is the answer :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Comment: If it's global, you can do `window[NameOfArray]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

`eval("myArray")`

It is an array which has the contents of myArray.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on where the array is defined, you can access it directly i.e. if it is defined globally as in your example:

```
console.log(window[NameOfArray][1]); // Outputs "ball"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to control the name of the variable NameOfArray, i.e. control the code, you could just set it as a variable on the window in that line using eval

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];
window.theArrayIWant = eval('myArray');
```

then using theArrayIWant moving forward